# Is this a helpful way of thinking about modular arithmetic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, axioms

Could one consider the structure of $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$ under addition and multiplication to simply be that of the ordinary integers, with one additional axiom - namely that $n=0$? So we would have $\mathbb{Z_{n}}=\{0,1,2,\ldots ,n-1\}$ as usual, for instance.

My question is whether this is a good way of thinking about $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$, or is there a subtlety that I've not considered that breaks it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, no subtle breakage-this works fine. It's a bit more formal to say the additional axiom is that $n$ is *equivalent* to $0$ and that you're calculating with representatives of equivalence classes in the resulting relation, but it amounts to the same thing when you get to actually doing modular arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks! I just thought it might be a good way to get students interested in the topic - *"What if $7=0$"* sounds dramatic at first, and once you have their attention you can talk about the genuine mathematics behind it.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: I think you are right, and as vadim123 says, it *is* enough to set it as axiom but you have to take all *consequences* into account.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could start with $n=0$, but there are a lot of consequences that are not at all obvious that you would need to derive.  For example, with the integers there are not two, each greater than 1, whose product is 1.  But modulo $7$ you have $2\times 4=1$.

Comment: But the concept of "greater than" doesn't really play any role in modular arithmetic.

Comment: So, $2\times 4=8=1+7=1$. I don't quite see your point.

Comment: I think he's saying that the existence of multiplicative inverses modulo $n$ is surprising. Which is a fair point, I think.

Comment: OK, certainly. It would be too bad if all the fun was in the axioms!